# EMRFS S3-optimized committer when using RDD and Datasets

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, amazon-emr, apache-spark-dataset

I want to use the EMRFS S3-optimized committer.
I set "spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled" to true when running a new step in spark EMR.
But I don't think it uses the optimized committer (_SUCCESS is 0 bytes).
How does EMR choose which committer to use?
Can it use the optimized for datasets and unoptimized for RDD? Because I have both in the same spark run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimized output committer is built-in EMR and used by default.
AWS optimized committer is activated only when it can: Until EMR 6.4.0 it worked only on some conditions: "Starting with Amazon EMR 6.4.0, this committer can be used for all common formats including parquet, ORC, and text-based formats (including CSV and JSON). For release versions prior to Amazon EMR 6.4.0, only the Parquet format is supported" - From AWS docs.

For me, there was an improvement of 50-60 percent in execution time.

The optimized committer [requeirments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-committer-reqs.html).

_SUCCESS files will still be 0 bytes. There are other OutputCommitters that do write content into them like the magic committer but are not fit for EMR and AWS advises not to use [them](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#Meet_the_S3A_Commmitters).

Comment: In my case, I'm not sure if its using EMRFS. Is there any way to confirm whether it is using EMRFS or not, from spark.

Comment: EMRFS is the default file system for Amazon EMR, so it is likely that Spark is using EMRFS. To be sure (From EMR docs): "To determine whether your application uses direct write in Amazon EMR 5.14.0 or later, enable Spark INFO logging. If a log line containing the text "Direct Write: ENABLED" is present in either Spark driver logs or Spark executor container logs, then your Spark application wrote using direct write". Direct write means - EMRFS is being used.